# How can I downgrade from python 3.6 to 2.7

Tags: python, downgrade

I was trying to load a python program but had invalid syntax problems as shown below. After doing some research I figured out that this error is because I have Python version 3.6 installed. How can I downgrade to a lower version of python that will run the program successfully?

Currently I am running (Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit))

```
 File "simple_loading.py", line 6

 print 'gray shape =>'+str(gray.shape)
                    ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: 3.6.0? Ubuntu has both 3.5 and 2.7 installed, but not (yet) 3.6. Which Ubuntu version are you on?

Comment: I am on 16.04 LTS

Comment: Try to start with: `python2.7 <programname>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have different environments with different versions of python: https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html

You should do something similar to:

`conda create --name NAME python=2.7`

NAME is the name of the environment and 2.7 i the version. Then you can change between the environments.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a script with python 2.7 you can do like this

```
python2 myscript.py
```

If you want to run a script with python 3.5 you can use

```
python3 myscript.py
```

[image]
More information about that here: [python 2 instead of python 3 as the (temporary) default python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237415/python-2-instead-of-python-3-as-the-temporary-default-python)